# Zone.js passes wrong currentZone value to onInvoke hook

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zone.js

there.

According to the comments for ZoneSpec interface (located in zone.ts file), onInvoke hook has to receive currentZone as second parameter. And if I create interceptor zone, then reference to that zone should be passed as second parameter.

Here is an excerpt from documentation:

```
/* Allows interception of the callback invocation.
@param parentZoneDelegate Delegate which performs the parent [ZoneSpec] operation.
@param currentZone The current [Zone] where the current interceptor has beed declared.
@param targetZone The [Zone] which originally received the request.
@param delegate The argument passed into the run method.
@param applyThis The argument passed into the run method.
@param applyArgs The argument passed into the run method.
@param source The argument passed into the run method.
*/
onInvoke?:
    (parentZoneDelegate: ZoneDelegate, currentZone: Zone, targetZone: Zone, delegate: Function,
     applyThis: any, applyArgs: any[], source: string) => any;
```

I created an interceptZone, which I suppose should be passed as current zone to my hook method. But for some reason I receive the same value as targetZone.
I created a demo [HERE](http://plnkr.co/edit/iwdW5x3EURKopuwtiX4s?p=preview), which depicts the described problem.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a bug in the library. Developers confirmed that.
Details are [HERE](https://github.com/angular/zone.js/pull/539)